# Inequality problem: $\tanh(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)\geq x^2(1-x^3)$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

> How to show that
>   $$\tanh(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)\geq x^2(1-x^3)$$
>   on $[0,1]$?

I tried to expand $\tanh(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)$ in a Taylor expansion:
$$\tanh(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)=\pi^2 x^2 - \frac{\pi^4 x^4}{2} + \frac{71 \pi^6 x^6}{360}+\cdots$$
But that doesn't seem to be helpful since $\pi^2 x^2 - \frac{\pi^4 x^4}{2}$ is not always greater than $x^2(1-x^3)$. What method can we use?

[image]

Comment: consider the function $f(x)=\tanh(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)-x^2(1-x^2)$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, the second $x^2$ should be $x^3$...

Comment: sorry it is $f(x)=\tanh(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)-x^2(1-x^3)$

Comment: you should  just show  $f\left( x \right) =\tanh { \left( \pi x \right) \sin { \left( \pi x \right)  }  } \\ g\left( x \right) ={ x }^{ 2 }\left( 1-{ x }^{ 3 } \right) \\ \max _{ \forall x\epsilon \left[ 0,1 \right]  }{ f\left( x \right) \ge \max _{ \forall x\epsilon \left[ 0,1 \right]  }{ g\left( x \right)  }  } $

Comment: @Nemo - that does not in general work.

Take $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ ($\max = 1$) and $g(x) = \sqrt[4]{5} x(1-x^4)$ ($\max = 4/5$), but $f(x) \ge g(x)$ is not true in this case...

Comment: @johannesvalks,i don't understand your exapmle,because the function is $f\left( x \right) =\tanh { \left( \pi x \right) \sin { \left( \pi x \right)  }  } \\$ your can see it from the graphic of functions,and i did't generalized it for all functions.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Split the inequality into

$$
\sin(\pi x) \ge \frac{\pi}{3} x ( 1 - x^3 )
$$

and
$$
\tanh(\pi x) \ge \frac{3}{\pi} x.
$$

Comment: just a suggestion ... The OP had tried a Taylor expansion, but did not find away forward.  It might help the reader if you would reference these separate inequalities or develop them herein.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV - I would to know more about it - but I have little time to dig deep into it...